# Creating maven repository on github

Tags: java, maven, github, repository

Trying to create my own maven repo on github to importing my java lybrary in other maven projects. But i taking exception Error creating blob: Not Found (404). Can anyone help with this problem?

When i trying "mvn clean deploy" :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.12:site (default) on project mavenRepoTest: Error creating blob: Not Found (404) -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenRepoTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
            <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <altDeploymentRepository>
                        internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo
                    </altDeploymentRepository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>
                    <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory>
                    <branch>refs/heads/mvn-repo</branch>
                    <merge>true</merge>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <repositoryName>https://github.com/Dilitand1/mavenRepoTest</repositoryName>
                    <repositoryOwner>Dilitand1</repositoryOwner>
                    <server>github</server>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Github's [Site Plugin](https://github.github.com/maven-plugins/site-plugin/) for maven, `repositoryName` has to be the name of the repository only, in this case `mavenRepoTest`.

Add the server to your maven properties like this:

```xml
<properties>
  <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
</properties>
```

Also make sure your GitHub credentials/OAuth2-Token are accessible by maven, for example by putting them into your `.m2/settings.xml`:

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <password>your-oauth-token-here</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: my problem was in password of server. I using password instead of token... Thx!